# "The connection string is missing the property: SharedAccessKeyName"

Tags: raspberry-pi3, raspbian, azure-iot-hub

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QVuOa.png)

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ iothub-explorer login HostName=roomautomation.azure-devices.net;SharedAccessKeyName=iothubowner;SharedAccessKey=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

/usr/local/lib/node_modules/iothub-explorer/node_modules/azure-iot-common/lib/connection_string.js:28
                throw new errors_1.ArgumentError(err + key);
                ^
ArgumentError: The connection string is missing the property: SharedAccessKeyName
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/iothub-explorer/node_modules/azure-iot-common/lib/connection_string.js:28:23
    at Array.forEach ()
    at Function.ConnectionString.parse (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/iothub-explorer/node_modules/azure-iot-common/lib/connection_string.js:26:24)
    at Object.parse (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/iothub-explorer/node_modules/azure-iothub/lib/connection_string.js:17:48)
    at Object. (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/iothub-explorer/iothub-explorer-login.js:33:27)
    at Module._compile (module.js:649:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:660:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:561:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:501:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:493:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:690:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:194:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:666:3

Comment: You can try add double quotation mark(" ") around the connection string to see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Rita's comment is correct, you need to add quotes around your connection string otherwise bash considers the first `;` character as the end of the command.